# Issues with htaccess redirecting http to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have an issue with my htaccess file in the server. When trying to redirect http to https it's gone crazy.

If i do this:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errores/error400.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errores/error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errores/error403.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&go=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&go=$2&action=$3
```

It works ok, just that is not redirecting http to https

But when i put this:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errores/error400.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errores/error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errores/error403.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&go=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&go=$2&action=$3
```

The server redirects to https but instead of putting the url like `https://server.com/en/home` it does `https://server.com/folder1/folder2/web/portal/en/home`

And i don't know what to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `/folder1/folder2/web/portal`? Are you using some CMS framework?

Comment: Sorry for delay, i was on a travel, no i'm not, it is a subfolder in my server. I have the main public_html/ and then the path you see in the question

Comment: But none of your rules are redirecting to `/folder1/folder2/web/portal` so there has to be some config somewhere redirecting to `/folder1/folder2/web/portal`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you match your rewrite rules with flags, especially for an HTTPS redirect.

Here's what worked for my production server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
```

When you put [L], it tells apache to stop processing the following rules, which also match `(.*)`.  You can find more information about that flag here: [RewriteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't worked, it removes the entire url after the host. https://server.comen/index instead of https://server.com/en/index

Comment: Perhaps in your case, a combination of both your original statement and my suggestion will work.  I would try using your `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` and `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` but add `[R=301,L]` right after the RewriteRule.